# Why am I able to load clearnet sites in Firefox configured for I2P? Should I be concerned regarding privacy?

Tags: i2p

Using I2P version 0.9.37-0, and after some difficulty I was able to set up Firefox with the settings at the bottom. I noticed that I am able to reach clearnet sites in the same browser, and that hadn't worked before. Should I be concerned about this?

I noticed this after trying out [ransack.i2p](https://www.reddit.com/r/i2p/comments/ad6omv/introducing_ransacki2p_a_metasearch_engine_on_i2p/) and clicking on a clearnet search result. Is it possible that clearnet sites load through i2p?

[image]

---

Sorry for the vague/inaccurate/sloppy description, I still need to get more familiar with the official terms. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit "[Hidden Services Manager](http://localhost:7657/i2ptunnelmgr)" from your "Router Console" homepage or directly (with defaults):
http://localhost:7657/i2ptunnelmgr

Configured by default are:

```
I2P HTTPS Proxy Port 4445
Outproxy: outproxy-tor.meeh.i2p
Description: HTTPS proxy for browsing eepsites and the web
```

and

```
I2P HTTP Proxy Port 4444
Outproxy: false.i2p
Description: HTTP proxy for browsing eepsites and the web
```

The outproxy listed is the server used to access clearnet. You can set up a Firefox extension such as [SwitchyOmega](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchyomega/) to only use the i2p proxies on *.i2p domains.